# How can I find the right dialog for a given process in pywinauto?

Tags: python, windows-10, pywinauto

I'm using pywinauto in windows 10. I'm currently unable to do much of anything because I can't seem to guess the right dialog to use.

This is the code I have:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application().start("Control Panel")

app.ControlPanel.print_control_identifiers()
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'ControlPanel' in 'dict_keys([])'
```

How can I know what to replace 'ControlPanel' with?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the app and reconnect
I hope it's works

```
import time
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().start("Control Panel")
app = Application().connect(title="All Control Panel Items", timeout=5)
time.sleep(2)
app.ControlPanel.print_control_identifiers()
```